# Rails custom model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have model user and I want create in model some method, call this method in helper, in controller Lists example and call this helper in view, but have error and don't know how to right write

my model User and my method

```
  def include_current_user
    User.where.not(id: current_user.id)
  end
```

my controller Lists and helper

```
  def shared_users
    @users ||= User.include_current_user
  end

  helper_method :shared_users
```

and my views where call helper

```
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:users, shared_users, :id, :email)%>
```

heave error

```
undefined method `include_current_user' for #<Class:0x007f389c649f98>
Did you mean?  included_modules
```

when I moved my method to self part
like this:

```
  class << self  
    def include_current_user
      where.not(id: current_user.id)
    end
  end
```

have error

```
undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<Class:0x007f38ac5d98c8>
Did you mean?  current_scope
```

current user this is helper in ssesion helper

```
  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end
```

maybe nned add variable for my method `include_current_user` and get 
in action call like this

```
  def shared_users
    @users ||= User.include_current_user(current_user)
  end
```

and method in model

```
  class << self  
    def include_current_user(user)
      where.not(id: user.id)
    end
  end
```

when created some query in action everything fine, like this

```
  def shared_users
    @users ||= User.where.not(id: current_user.id)
  end

  helper_method :shared_users
```

But I want create method in model, mayde more complicated, how do right way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **change method `include_current_user` to class method**
2. **current_user not exist on model**

Model:

```
def self.include_current_user current_user
   User.where.not(id: current_user.id)
end
```

controller:

```
def shared_users
  @users ||= User.include_current_user current_user
end
```

Comment: I add variable to method and this work but I have question - this is right way?

Comment: Yes, current_user only exist on session. It mean you only call it on views or controllers

Answer (score 0):

`include_current_user` is not a class method. Hence you cannot call it without referring to an object of `User` class. Try defining `include_current_user` as `self.include_current_user`. This will make it a class method. Then you will be able to call it as `User.include_current_user`.

Comment: This still won't solve his issue, as current user won't be available in the model.  @shuba.ivan You'll need to pass the current user into the method, and also deal with the possibility that it's nil.

Comment: @j-dexx -- he made clear that `@users ||= User.where.not(id: current_user.id)` is working fine. That means that `current_user` may already be defined on class level.

Comment: He says current user is in a helper.  It won't be available in the model unless he includes it.